# function missing 1 required positional argument: 't' how do I make it go away?

Tags: python

Hi I'm writing a code for a function that is supposed to use the RK4 method to solve different ODEs. I've gotten to the point where I solved the first eqn and now I'm on the second(fb2). I made my RK4 code use an if statement to differentiate between the types of ODEs(but if theres a better way to make it work I'm all ears). Basically the one for the second function(fb2) is asking for the positional argument for t which I thought I accounted for in my RK4 function. I'm new to coding so any help is very much appreciated. Here's my entire code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#defining functions
H0=7 #initial height, meters
def f2a(t,H,k,Vin,D):
    dhdt=4/(math.pi*D**2)*(Vin-k*np.sqrt(H))
    return(dhdt)

def fb2(J,t):
    x=J[0]
    y=J[1]
    dxdt=0.25*y-x
    dydt=3*x-y
    #X0,Y0=1,1 initial conditions
    return([dxdt,dydt])



#x0 and y0 are initial conditions

def odeRK4(function,tspan,R,h,*args):

    #R is vector of inital conditions
    x0=R[0]
    y0=R[1]


    #writing statement for what to do if h isnt given/other thing
    if h==None:
        h=.01*(tspan[1]-tspan[0])
    elif h> tspan[1]-tspan[0]:
        h=.01*(tspan[1]-tspan[0]) 
    else:
        h=h
    #defining the 2-element array (i hope)
    #pretty sure tspan is range of t values
    x0=tspan[0] #probably 0 if this is meant for time
    xn=tspan[1] #whatever time we want it to end at?
    #xn is final x value-t
    #x0 is initial

    t_values=np.arange(x0,xn+h,h) #range of values based on increments of h
    N=len(t_values)
    y_val=np.zeros(N)
    y_val[0]=y0
    #I am trying to print all the Y values into this array
    if function==fb2:
        y_val=np.zeros([2,N])#makes 2 vectors, this makes it possible for : to apply
        y_val[:,0]=y0
        for i in range(1,N):
            #rk4 method
            #k1
            k1=function(y_val[:,i-1],*args)
            t1=t_values[i-1] +h/2 #started range @ 1, n-1 starts at 0
            y1=y_val[:,i-1]+0.5*h*k1
             
            #k2
            k2=function(y1,*args)
            t2=t_values[i-1]+0.5*h
            y2=y_val[:,i-1]+0.5*k2*h
     
            #k3
            k3=function(y2,*args)
            t3=t_values[i-1]+0.5*h
            y3=y_val[:,i-1]+k3*h
    
            #k4
            k4=function(y3,*args)
    
            new=(1/6)*h*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
    
            y_val[:,i]=y_val[:,i-1]+h*new
            #this fills the t_val array and keeps the loop going

        a=np.column_stack((t_values,y_val))
        print('At time t, Y= (t on left,Y on right)')
        print(a)
        plt.plot(t_values,y_val)

    elif function==f2a:
        y_val=np.zeros(N)
        y_val[0]=y0
        for i in range(1,N):
            #k1
            t1=t_values[i-1] #started range @ 1, n-1 starts at 0
            y1=y_val[i-1]
            k1=function(t1,y1,*args) 
           
            t2=t_values[i-1]+0.5*h
            y2=y_val[i-1]+0.5*k1*h
            k2=function(t2,y2,*args) #computing k2
        
            t3=t_values[i-1]+0.5*h
            y3=y_val[i-1]+0.5*k2*h
            k3=function(t3,y3,*args) #computing k3

            t4=t_values[i-1]+h
            y4=y_val[i-1]+h*k3
            k4=function(t4,y4,*args) #computing k4
        
            y_val[i]=y_val[i-1]+(1/6)*h*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
            #using rk4 eqn from workbook to calc new q
        a=np.column_stack((t_values,y_val))
        print('At time t, Y= (t on left,Y on right)')
        print(a)
        plt.plot(t_values,y_val)
    

print('For 3A:')
#k=10, told by professor bc not included in instructions
odeRK4(f2a, [0,20],[0,7], None, 10,150,7)

print('for 3B:')
odeRK4(fb2,[0,20],[1,1],None)
```

Comment: you must pass 2 parameters to ```fb2``` you called it twice, it expects you to give it ```J``` and ```t```.

Comment: `odeRK4(fb2,[0,20],[1,1],None)`  passes 4 arguments but the function accepts 4 plus * args so there is no *args so no t passed to fb2

Comment: @user19077881 I don't know what that means... I define t values in my rk4 function and it passes fine for the first function but not for the second. For this program I have been told that I shouldn't need to define t. Is there a problem in the rk4 that is stopping it from identifying t? Sorry I'm extremly new to this.

Comment: Just count the number of things you are using as arguments to a function when you call it and the number expected by the function and you will see the mismatch. Simply, you are not passing anything which accepted as t.